# Error with accessing Array name in perl

Tags: perl

I am doing a project in perl to search each elements from an array with all the other element and print the element and the array name in which the match occours.

Since the code is very long I'm explaining my problem with short example.

```
@array1=(sdasd,asdasd,abc);

if(abc=~/$array1[2]/)
{
print"Found!";
}
else
{
print"not found!"
}
```

When i try searching for the pattern with the above method I get the answer. As there are many arrays and each array contain many elements i gave array name as @array1 , @array2 ... so that i can search using loops .

so i tried this method

```
@array1=(sdasd,asdasd,abc);

$arrayno = 1;
if(abc=~$array$arrayno[2])
{
print"Found!";
}
else
{
print"not found!"
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
(Missing operator before $no?)
syntax error at C:\Perl64\prac\pp.pl line 4, near "$arra$no"
Execution of C:\Perl64\prac\pp.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Don't do that. Use a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much simpler to hold all of your arrays in the same structure, you can place as many arrayrefs as you like inside of an array and iterate over them in a nested foreach loop:

```
my @arrays = ( [1,  2,  3,  4],
               [5,  6,  7,  8],
               [9, 10, 11, 12],
             );

my $array_counter = 1; 
foreach my $aref ( @arrays ) {
   foreach my $elem ( @$aref ) { # place arrayref in list context
      # do comparison here
      if ( # MATCH ) { print "Found match in Array $array_counter\n"; }
   }
   $array_counter++; # increment counter 
}
```

Comment: Im confused.. Could You please give a small example .. And also is it possible to refer each row with a name? Because i should from which row the two element matches

Comment: Well, you can use a variable to store the array that you are currently matching against. I will edit above to give an example.